# PHP CodeIgniter encrypt class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to ask you whether it is safe to use this class to store users' passwords in database.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

I generated some random string (32 chars) as encryption key.

For encryption I would use `$this->encrypt->encode($pwd)`
The only thing I would like to know whether it is safe or I should use md5 or sha1 or something different.

THanks

Comment: A Codeigniter library called 'tank_auth' is using PHPass_HASH encryption. This is a really strong encryption lib. And In my opinion the best. MD5 isn't safe at all.

Comment: use md5 for strong hashing or if you want to decrypt your password then use codeigniter encrypt and decrypt

Comment: Passwords should not be _encoded_ [reversible], but **hashed** [irreversible]: the difference is crucial!

Comment: @Sundar - you're right about using hashing rather than encryption for passwords, but **do not** use MD5. It is **not** a strong hash (even with salt it can be broken easily). Use bcrypt or sha1 instead, with salt. These hashes are secure.

Comment: also thanks for the rest of comments it helped me to decide

Comment: Also you can try [CodeIgniter Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty safe because decryption will need access to your salt key, in the config file. But I recommend you only use this method if you REALLY need decryption. For passwords usually is not needed.

Better than that, use SHA1. Double encrypt your passwords with a random seed.

```
$seed = random_string();
$pwd = sha1($pwd . $this->config->item('encryption_key'));
$pwd = sha1($pwd . $seed);
```

Then store both (pwd and seed) in your database. When checking if password match, encrypt with SQL.